# Create Azure Web App fails saying it already exists

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, azure-webapps, azure-resource-group

I create resource-group :

```
PS > az group create -l westus -n rg-appsvc
```

Then I create app-service :

```
PS > az appservice plan create --resource-group=rg-appsvc --name appsvc-plan-test --sku S1
```

Then I create web-service :

```
PS > az webapp create --resource-group rg-appsvc  --plan appsvc-plan-test --name webapp-test
```

> Webapp 'webapp-test' already exists. The command will use the existing
> app's settings. Unable to retrieve details of the existing app
> 'webapp-test'. Please check that the app is a part of the current
> subscription

```
PS > az webapp list                                                                                     
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a Web App, its name will be a subdomain of **azurewebsites.net**. Looks like the **webapp-test** name is already in use. Try using a different name.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to quickly pre-test if a name exists ?

Comment: Not with the Azure CLI. You can quickly test if the name is available using the Portal.